# AngularJS - Filter checkbox with numbers/length

Tags: angularjs, forms, radio-button

I have an app that searches various tickets.
In the sidebar I have some filters so the user can filter down on their results(these include checkboxes and radio buttons like eBay/Amazon etc.).

So it looks similar to this in the sidebar:

### How to Buy

Direct Debit (10)
Cash (2)

So the user knows from a glance that if they click on Direct Debit it will return 10 results. The problem I then have is that when the user clicks on  Direct Debit, the radio buttons change to this...

### How to Buy

Direct Debit (10)
Cash (0)

This would be correct if it were a checkbox, as click on Direct Debit AND Cash would return 0 results. However in this case (a radio button) the user should still see that there are 2 results if they click on Cash.

Here is my code...

### HTML

```
<ul class="checkbox-list nga-fast nga-collapse" data-ng-show="ticketing.filterButtons.OperatorBtn">
  <li data-ng-repeat="filter in ticketing.filterButtons.Operator | orderBy: filter" data-ng-if="filter != null">
    <input id="operator{{$index}}" name="operator{{$index}}" type="radio" class="stylized" data-ng-model="ticketing.searchFilters.Operator" data-ng-change="ticketing.update()" value="{{filter}}" />
    <label for="operator{{$index}}">{{filter}} 
      ({{ (ticketing.filteredTickets | filter: {Operator: filter}).length}})
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### JS

```
function update() {
  var filtered = vm.all;
  console.log(vm.searchFilters);
  // For each filter in the search filters loop through and delete any that state false, this is so it doesn't explicitly match false and shows everything.
  angular.forEach(vm.searchFilters, function(val, key) {
    // if Key/Property contains 'Allow" and the value is true || if Key/Property doesn't contain 'Allow' and val is false (this is to make sure the oppposite/exclude filter values are deleted as the trues will be falses and vice versa)
    if ((key.indexOf('Allow') !== -1 && val) || (val == false && key.indexOf('Allow') === -1)) {
      // Delete the filter and value
      delete vm.searchFilters[key];
    }
  });

  // Filter results by the filters selected
  filtered = $filter('filter')(filtered, vm.searchFilters);

  // Sort results by selected option
  vm.filteredTickets = $filter('orderBy')(filtered, vm.orderBy);

  console.log(vm.filteredTickets);
  console.log(vm.searchFilters);

  vm.updateGrid();
}
```

If you require any more info or code then please let me know and i'll provide it.

Comment: can you provide any demo?

Comment: I would parameteralize (is that even a word?) the input-type, and use that type in your filter to determine how to filter your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess. There might be something go wrong in the below line

```
     ({{ (ticketing.filteredTickets | filter: { Operator:filter}).length}})
```

on Clicking of `Direct Debit";`  you might have updated "ticketing.filteredTickets" with only data of "Direct Debit" hence there is not data for "Cash"